# How can I get the average grade of each list from a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently getting a `"TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' "` message. Here is my code

```
def studentGrades(gradeList):
    avgGrades = [ ]
    for element in gradeList:
        isinstance(element, int)
        i = 0
        for j in element:
            i = i + j
        average = (sum(element) / len(element))
        avgGrades.append(average)
    return avgGrades
```

Comment: `isinstance(element, int)` does nothing. You ignore the return value.

Comment: seeing the `gradeList` will help.

Comment: Show an example I can run. What is `gradeList`?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. Once you post a question, they
  belong to the site and its users. Even if it is no longer useful to
  you, it might still be  beneficial to someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you just need to convert j to an int, like this:

```
for j in element:

    i = i + int(j)
```